# duplicate entry based on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have two tables with multible columns and i want to find where one name i table 1 has the same father in table 2. 
I tryed this :

```
SELECT
    d0.DateOfBirth,
    d.Id,d.Reg,
    d.Name, 
    D0.Id, 
    D0.FatherId,
    d1.Reg as Father_reg, 
    D1.Name as Fathers_Name, 
    D0.MotherId,
    d2.Reg as Mother_Reg, 
    D2.Name as Mothers_Name, 
FROM 
    dbo.Dogs d 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Litters D0 ON D0.Id = d.LitterId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Dogs D1 on D0.FatherId=D1.ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Dogs D2 on D0.MotherId=D2.ID
WHERE 
    d.Name IN (
        SELECT d.Name 
        FROM dbo.Dogs D 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Litters D0 ON D0.Id = d.LitterId 
        GROUP BY d.Name  
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
ORDER BY
    d.Name, 
    d0.DateOfBirth
```

This gives me all the duplicate names but i want all duplicate names that has the same father.

So even if "Frank" is four times in the table but only 2 of those times his father is named "Ian" then it should only list those two entrys. The problem im having is that names are in table dbo.dogs and the connection between offspring ID and father ID are in table dbo.litters so when i try to make a selection i do the count in a subquery and is only allowed one selction there. english is not my native language so i hope it made some sense ;)

I made a fiddle to see the data **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc03f4e4334d605081bccc8dedf7b68d)**.

What i would like to see is this:

```
DateOfBirth Id  Reg Name    Id  FatherId    Father_reg  Fathers_Name    MotherId    Mother_Reg  Mothers_Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/04/2012 00:00:00 3   NO34567/2012    Fido    9000    2   NO12345/2010    king    1   NO23456/2009    Queen    
01/04/2012 00:00:00 6   NO34567/2012    Fido    9000    2   NO12345/2010    king    1   NO23456/2009    Queen
```

The two top row in the fiddle where the fathers name is the same and filter out where the fathers names are just one time.

**Solution in Fiddle : [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1737c894eb81809470a23ffd091552d)**

Comment: Would you please edit your question to display sample data for tables `Dogs`, `Countries`, `Litters`, and the corresponding expected output? This will help people understand exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Now you would just need to show what are your expected results.

Comment: Are you using SQLServer, as showned in the fiddle?

Comment: yes its like the fiddle :)

Comment: Now your question looks better, and you are getting answers and upvotes. Keep the sample data/expected results in mind for your next question... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM dogs d LEFT JOIN litters l ON d.LitterId = l.id
```

```
ID | Reg          | Name   | LitterID |   ID | Dateofbirth         | FatherID | motherID
:- | :----------- | :----- | :------- | ---: | :------------------ | -------: | -------:
3  | NO34567/2012 | Fido   | 9000     | 9000 | 01/04/2012 00:00:00 |        2 |        1
4  | NO34568/2012 | Fido   | 6000     | 6000 | 01/06/2014 00:00:00 |        9 |        8
5  | NO34569/2012 | Fido   | 5000     | 5000 | 01/05/2013 00:00:00 |        7 |        8
6  | NO34567/2012 | Fido   | 9000     | 9000 | 01/04/2012 00:00:00 |        2 |        1
2  | NO12345/2010 | king   | 8000     | null | null                |     null |     null
1  | NO23456/2009 | Queen  | 7000     | null | null                |     null |     null
7  | NO12346/2010 | God    | 8000     | null | null                |     null |     null
8  | NO23457/2009 | Godess | 7000     | null | null                |     null |     null
9  | NO12346/2010 | Devil  | 8000     | null | null                |     null |     null
```

---

I understand that you are looking for dogs who have the same father *and* the same name. In SQL Server, a simple solution is to use window function `COUNT(...) OVER(...)` to count how many such duplicates exist for each record.

Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        d.ID, 
        d.Reg, 
        d.Name, 
        d.LitterID, 
        l.Dateofbirth, 
        l.FatherID, 
        l.MotherID, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY d.Name, l.FatherId) cnt
    FROM dogs d 
    LEFT JOIN litters l ON d.LitterId = l.ID
) x WHERE cnt > 1
```

Yields:

```
ID | Reg          | Name | LitterID | Dateofbirth         | FatherID | motherID | cnt
:- | :----------- | :--- | :------- | :------------------ | -------: | -------: | --:
3  | NO34567/2012 | Fido | 9000     | 01/04/2012 00:00:00 |        2 |        1 |   2
6  | NO34567/2012 | Fido | 9000     | 01/04/2012 00:00:00 |        2 |        1 |   2
```

---

Now all that is left to do is a few additional self-joins to retrive the name of the parents:

```
SELECT
    x.DateOfBirth,
    x.ID,
    x.Reg,
    x.Name,
    x.FatherID,
    d_father.Reg FatherReg,
    d_father.Name FatherName,
    x.MotherID,
    d_mother.Reg MotherReg,
    d_mother.Name MotherName
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            d.ID, 
            d.Reg, 
            d.Name, 
            d.LitterID, 
            l.Dateofbirth, 
            l.FatherID, 
            l.MotherID, 
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY d.Name, l.FatherId) cnt
        FROM dogs d 
        LEFT JOIN litters l ON d.LitterId = l.ID
    ) x 
    INNER JOIN dogs d_mother ON d_mother.ID = x.MotherID
    INNER JOIN dogs d_father ON d_father.ID = x.FatherID
WHERE x.cnt > 1
```

Results:

```
DateOfBirth         | ID | Reg          | Name | FatherID | FatherReg    | FatherName | MotherID | MotherReg    | MotherName
:------------------ | :- | :----------- | :--- | -------: | :----------- | :--------- | -------: | :----------- | :---------
01/04/2012 00:00:00 | 3  | NO34567/2012 | Fido |        2 | NO12345/2010 | king       |        1 | NO23456/2009 | Queen     
01/04/2012 00:00:00 | 6  | NO34567/2012 | Fido |        2 | NO12345/2010 | king       |        1 | NO23456/2009 | Queen
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=281e1c06c26df008bee37f1c3ef7834c)**

Comment: This works, but is it possible to tweak it to check the mother and fathers names instead of Id? In some instances even the name can be misspelled but in most cases de have multiple Id`s. This is an old DB from the 1990`s and back then they where happy just to get the data into the DB

Comment: I figured it out and it now works perfectly. Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use Litter ID in your in clause instead of name since Fido is repeated multiple times, and looks like your join is based on litter ID. If you do that, you will get your expected output.

```
Select  d0.DateOfBirth,d.Id,d.Reg,d.Name, D0.Id , D0.FatherId,d1.Reg as Father_reg, D1.Name as Fathers_Name, D0.MotherId,d2.Reg as Mother_Reg, D2.Name as Mothers_Name
from dbo.Dogs d 
     join dbo.Litters D0 on D0.Id = d.LitterId
     join dbo.Dogs D1 on D0.FatherId=D1.ID
     join dbo.Dogs D2 on D0.MotherId=D2.ID
where d.LitterId in (select d.LitterId from dbo.Dogs D left join dbo.Litters D0 on D0.Id = d.LitterId Group by d.LitterId  having COUNT(*) > 1)
order by d.Name, d0.DateOfBirth
```

Output:

```
DateOfBirth        Id    Reg           Name     Id   FatherId Father_reg Fathers_Name   MotherId    Mother_Reg  Mothers_Name
01/04/2012 00:00:00 3   NO34567/2012    Fido    9000    2   NO12345/2010    king    1   NO23456/2009    Queen
01/04/2012 00:00:00 6   NO34567/2012    Fido    9000    2   NO12345/2010    king    1   NO23456/2009    Queen
```

Comment: The problem ,and i see that i have made the testbase to good, is that Fido can have many different litterIds with the same father. In some instances even the name can be misspelled but in most cases de have multiple Ids.but i got a solution to work thank you for the help.